# trouble getting unbalanced df from wide to long

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have an unbalanced, wide dataframe that looks something like this:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id1=seq(1:10),
                 id2=runif(10),
                 v1.a=runif(10), 
                 v1.b=runif(10),
                 v1.c=runif(10),
                 v2.a=runif(10), 
                 v2.b=runif(10),
                 v2.c=runif(10),
                 v3.a=runif(10), 
                 #v3.b=runif(10),
                 v3.c=runif(10),
                 v4.a=runif(10), 
                 v4.b=runif(10),
                 v4.c=runif(10),
                 #v5.a=runif(10), 
                 #v5.b=runif(10),
                 v5.c=runif(10),
                 v6.a=runif(10), 
                 v6.b=runif(10),
                 v6.c=runif(10),
                 v7.a=rep(NA, 10), 
                 v7.b=rep(NA, 10),
                 v7.c=rep(NA, 10),
                 v8.d=runif(10))
```

And I'm trying to get it into a long format. `reshape` failed because not all varying columns are present in every time, so I turned to `Reshape` in `splitstackshape`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
vary <- grep("\\.a$|\\.b$|\\.c$|\\.d$", names(df))
stubs <- unique(sub("\\..*$", "", names(df[vary])))
df2 <- Reshape(df, 
               id.vars=c("id1", "id2"), 
               var.stubs=stubs, 
               sep=".")
```

However, the end result does not seem quite right. For instance, `v3` is missing inputs for "b", which I would have assumed is time 2. In `df2`, there are long `v3` values for times 1 and 2, but not 3.

```
   id1        id2 time         v1         v2        v3
1    1 0.26550866    1 0.20597457 0.82094629 0.3390729
2    2 0.37212390    1 0.17655675 0.64706019 0.8394404
3    3 0.57285336    1 0.68702285 0.78293276 0.3466835
4    4 0.90820779    1 0.38410372 0.55303631 0.3337749
5    5 0.20168193    1 0.76984142 0.52971958 0.4763512
6    6 0.89838968    1 0.49769924 0.78935623 0.8921983
7    7 0.94467527    1 0.71761851 0.02333120 0.8643395
8    8 0.66079779    1 0.99190609 0.47723007 0.3899895
9    9 0.62911404    1 0.38003518 0.73231374 0.7773207
10  10 0.06178627    1 0.77744522 0.69273156 0.9606180
11   1 0.26550866    2 0.93470523 0.47761962 0.4346595
12   2 0.37212390    2 0.21214252 0.86120948 0.7125147
13   3 0.57285336    2 0.65167377 0.43809711 0.3999944
14   4 0.90820779    2 0.12555510 0.24479728 0.3253522
15   5 0.20168193    2 0.26722067 0.07067905 0.7570871
16   6 0.89838968    2 0.38611409 0.09946616 0.2026923
17   7 0.94467527    2 0.01339033 0.31627171 0.7111212
18   8 0.66079779    2 0.38238796 0.51863426 0.1216919
19   9 0.62911404    2 0.86969085 0.66200508 0.2454885
20  10 0.06178627    2 0.34034900 0.40683019 0.1433044
21   1 0.26550866    3 0.48208012 0.91287592        NA
22   2 0.37212390    3 0.59956583 0.29360337        NA
23   3 0.57285336    3 0.49354131 0.45906573        NA
24   4 0.90820779    3 0.18621760 0.33239467        NA
25   5 0.20168193    3 0.82737332 0.65087047        NA
26   6 0.89838968    3 0.66846674 0.25801678        NA
27   7 0.94467527    3 0.79423986 0.47854525        NA
28   8 0.66079779    3 0.10794363 0.76631067        NA
29   9 0.62911404    3 0.72371095 0.08424691        NA
30  10 0.06178627    3 0.41127443 0.87532133        NA
```

Am I making a mistake?

Is there a better alternative using `melt` or `gather`? I tried a few approaches, but I did not have much luck. My actual use case consists of 1302 of what I'm calling `vary` columns, 3 time periods (a, b, c), and 821 unique `stubs` (so clearly unbalanced).

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Relevant for when you don't have every combination of variables - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713846/reshape-messy-longitudinal-survey-data-containing-multiple-different-variables/34714134

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, adapting from the other linked answer:

```
spl <- strsplit(names(df)[-(1:2)],"\\.")
allvars <- c(outer(unique(sapply(spl,`[`,1)), unique(sapply(spl,`[`,2)),paste,sep="."))
df[setdiff(allvars, names(df))] <- NA

reshape(df, direction="long", sep=".", varying=allvars)

#     id1        id2 time         v1         v2        v3         v4        v5         v6 v7         v8 id
#1.a    1 0.26550866    a 0.20597457 0.82094629 0.3390729 0.23962942        NA 0.57487220 NA         NA  1
#2.a    2 0.37212390    a 0.17655675 0.64706019 0.8394404 0.05893438        NA 0.07706438 NA         NA  2
#...
```

Comment: Thanks, @thelatemail. When I run this, it looks like `v3` has values for times `a` and `b`, but not `c` or `d`. Given the input `df`, I only expect values for times `a` and `c`.

Comment: True, something funny is happening. Let me look

Comment: @EricGreen - fixed it, just had to reference the `varying=` by names explicitly.

Comment: This looks right, @thelatemail. I like the use of `reshape`.

Comment: @EricGreen - just be sure that you have your variables in the right order within each group in the `allvars` variable, e.g. `v1.a` then `v1.b` then `v1.c` etc. It seems to affect the order of the results.

Answer (score 3):

What I think you're going for, with tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)

       # gather non-ID columns to long form
df %>% gather(var, val, -id1:-id2) %>% 
  # split former column names into variable name and time variables
  separate(var, c('var', 'time')) %>% 
  # spread back to wide form
  spread(var, val) %>%
  head()

##   id1       id2 time        v1        v2        v3         v4        v5         v6 v7        v8
## 1   1 0.2655087    a 0.2059746 0.8209463 0.3390729 0.23962942        NA 0.57487220 NA        NA
## 2   1 0.2655087    b 0.9347052 0.4776196        NA 0.65472393        NA 0.68278808 NA        NA
## 3   1 0.2655087    c 0.4820801 0.9128759 0.4346595 0.97617069 0.9918386 0.61464497 NA        NA
## 4   1 0.2655087    d        NA        NA        NA         NA        NA         NA NA 0.2847905
## 5   2 0.3721239    a 0.1765568 0.6470602 0.8394404 0.05893438        NA 0.07706438 NA        NA
## 6   2 0.3721239    b 0.2121425 0.8612095        NA 0.35319727        NA 0.60154122 NA        NA
```

Comment: Thanks, @alistaire. This seems really elegant.

Comment: I can't quite get this working on my actual use case, but I like the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, we can use `melt` from `data.table` which can take multiple `patterns` in the `measure`.  It is easier with `data.table` as it takes multiple patterns

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
d1 <- read.table(text=names(df)[-(1:2)], sep=".")
df[, (setdiff(outer(d1$V1, d1$V2, FUN = paste, sep="."), names(df)[-(1:2)])) := NA]

melt(df[, order(names(df)), with = FALSE], measure = patterns(paste0("v", 
                1:8)), value.name = paste0("v", 1:8))
```

---

Or it could be `melt/dcast`

```
res <- dcast(melt(df, id.var = c("id1", "id2"))[, c("var1", "var2") := 
     tstrsplit(variable, "[.]")], id1 + id2 + var2 ~ var1, value.var = "value")
res[order(var2, id1)]
#    id1        id2 var2         v1         v2        v3         v4        v5         v6 v7         v8
# 1:   1 0.26550866    a 0.20597457 0.82094629 0.3390729 0.23962942        NA 0.57487220 NA         NA
# 2:   2 0.37212390    a 0.17655675 0.64706019 0.8394404 0.05893438        NA 0.07706438 NA         NA
# 3:   3 0.57285336    a 0.68702285 0.78293276 0.3466835 0.64228826        NA 0.03554058 NA         NA
# 4:   4 0.90820779    a 0.38410372 0.55303631 0.3337749 0.87626921        NA 0.64279549 NA         NA
# 5:   5 0.20168193    a 0.76984142 0.52971958 0.4763512 0.77891468        NA 0.92861520 NA         NA
# 6:   6 0.89838968    a 0.49769924 0.78935623 0.8921983 0.79730883        NA 0.59809242 NA         NA
# 7:   7 0.94467527    a 0.71761851 0.02333120 0.8643395 0.45527445        NA 0.56090075 NA         NA
# 8:   8 0.66079779    a 0.99190609 0.47723007 0.3899895 0.41008408        NA 0.52602772 NA         NA
# 9:   9 0.62911404    a 0.38003518 0.73231374 0.7773207 0.81087024        NA 0.98509522 NA         NA
#10:  10 0.06178627    a 0.77744522 0.69273156 0.9606180 0.60493329        NA 0.50764182 NA         NA
#11:   1 0.26550866    b 0.93470523 0.47761962        NA 0.65472393        NA 0.68278808 NA         NA
#12:   2 0.37212390    b 0.21214252 0.86120948        NA 0.35319727        NA 0.60154122 NA         NA
#13:   3 0.57285336    b 0.65167377 0.43809711        NA 0.27026015        NA 0.23886868 NA         NA
#14:   4 0.90820779    b 0.12555510 0.24479728        NA 0.99268406        NA 0.25816593 NA         NA
#15:   5 0.20168193    b 0.26722067 0.07067905        NA 0.63349326        NA 0.72930962 NA         NA
#16:   6 0.89838968    b 0.38611409 0.09946616        NA 0.21320814        NA 0.45257083 NA         NA
#17:   7 0.94467527    b 0.01339033 0.31627171        NA 0.12937235        NA 0.17512677 NA         NA
#18:   8 0.66079779    b 0.38238796 0.51863426        NA 0.47811803        NA 0.74669827 NA         NA
#19:   9 0.62911404    b 0.86969085 0.66200508        NA 0.92407447        NA 0.10498764 NA         NA
#20:  10 0.06178627    b 0.34034900 0.40683019        NA 0.59876097        NA 0.86454495 NA         NA
#21:   1 0.26550866    c 0.48208012 0.91287592 0.4346595 0.97617069 0.9918386 0.61464497 NA         NA
#22:   2 0.37212390    c 0.59956583 0.29360337 0.7125147 0.73179251 0.4955936 0.55715954 NA         NA
#23:   3 0.57285336    c 0.49354131 0.45906573 0.3999944 0.35672691 0.4843495 0.32877732 NA         NA
#24:   4 0.90820779    c 0.18621760 0.33239467 0.3253522 0.43147369 0.1734423 0.45313145 NA         NA
#25:   5 0.20168193    c 0.82737332 0.65087047 0.7570871 0.14821156 0.7548209 0.50044097 NA         NA
#26:   6 0.89838968    c 0.66846674 0.25801678 0.2026923 0.01307758 0.4538955 0.18086636 NA         NA
#27:   7 0.94467527    c 0.79423986 0.47854525 0.7111212 0.71556607 0.5111698 0.52963060 NA         NA
#28:   8 0.66079779    c 0.10794363 0.76631067 0.1216919 0.10318424 0.2075451 0.07527575 NA         NA
#29:   9 0.62911404    c 0.72371095 0.08424691 0.2454885 0.44628435 0.2286581 0.27775593 NA         NA
#30:  10 0.06178627    c 0.41127443 0.87532133 0.1433044 0.64010105 0.5957120 0.21269952 NA         NA
#31:   1 0.26550866    d         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA         NA NA 0.28479048
#32:   2 0.37212390    d         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA         NA NA 0.89509410
#33:   3 0.57285336    d         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA         NA NA 0.44623532
#34:   4 0.90820779    d         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA         NA NA 0.77998489
#35:   5 0.20168193    d         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA         NA NA 0.88061903
#36:   6 0.89838968    d         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA         NA NA 0.41312421
#37:   7 0.94467527    d         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA         NA NA 0.06380848
#38:   8 0.66079779    d         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA         NA NA 0.33548749
#39:   9 0.62911404    d         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA         NA NA 0.72372595
#40:  10 0.06178627    d         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA         NA NA 0.33761533
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. I believe these approaches give different solutions. `dcast` looks like what I expected.

Comment: @EricGreen I fixed the first approach.

Comment: in my actual example I have a lot of character variables. It seems like the `melt/dcast` approach using `data.table` is converting to integers. This is outside the scope of the original question—and your solution addresses the toy example—but maybe you will recognize my problem.

Comment: @EricGreen In that case, you may have to do this separately for those character and numeric column.